# Problems assigning incremented values to CGPointMake

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, cgfloat

I'm trying to use the following code to move through pages of a Pdf using webView.

```
 float Y = pdfNavigateController.webView.center.y + gY;
 [pdfNavigateController.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,Y)];
```

The value gY is also a float and is incremented as the user selects the next page. The code is currently throwing an error 'Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGFloat' (aka 'float') and 'float *'). I'm guessing the operands are invalid as the value is a pointer but I don't know how to pass the incremented value without getting this error.

Comment: Could you show us exactly where gY comes from, or how it's instanciated. As the error seems to read like you're trying to add a float* (float pointer) to float (CGFloat). This kind of suggests that gY is in fact declared as float*.

Comment: What is gY in your code? Where is it declared?

Comment: gY is declare as static float *gY = 0 at the top of the page under the declarations, along with all other global variables. It is incremented before it reaches the code you see above. The idea is that the code above is run after each time the 'Next' button is pressed to move on to the next page. It is the code above that is causing the problems as it wont accept gY as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If gY is a pointer (to a float), you need to dereference it in order to access its value:

```
float Y = pdfNavigateController.webView.center.y + *gY;
```

**EDIT**

Make sure you've got a valid pointer (i.e., gY points to an actual float).
If it's an un-initialized pointer, it won't work.

Can you please tell us how do you get `gY`?

**EDIT 2**

I've seen you said that gY is declared as:

```
static float *gY = 0;
```

That's a NULL pointer.
And you can't dereference a NULL pointer.

When you increment it, you increment the pointer (the memory address), not the value.
So your pointer actually points to garbage.

Why do you use a pointer?
You should use:

```
static float gY = 0;
```

Comment: As above the code hangs on this line even if I wrap an exception handler around it.

Comment: Thanks that works ok now, I really appreciate your comments, silly mistake referencing a NULL pointer but glad you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

if `gY` is a pointer to a float use `*gY`:

```
float Y = pdfNavigateController.webView.center.y + *gY;
```

The error rmessage: `('CGFloat' (aka 'float') and 'float *')`
is saying that `CGFloat` expected a `float` but got a float pointer: `float *`

For debugging first break the operation down into accessing the value pointed to.

```
float gYValue = *gY;
float Y = pdfNavigateController.webView.center.y + gYValue;
```

Comment: The code above compiles ok but it hangs on the line float gYValue = *gY;

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to troubleshoot since you've  posted very small amount of your code. However I have an idea. If the gX is an argument of a method the solution may be following:

In order to fix this problem, add the declaration of the method to the .h file for your class. Hope this will help - if not please post some more code.